# Twitter fetching application only bearer token HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, android, twitter-oauth

I am trying to fetch the application only bearer token by using my consumer key and consumer secret following [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token). This is my implementation:

```
public class OAuthApplicationOnlyBearerTokenFetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static Logger logger =
            Logger.getLogger(OAuthApplicationOnlyBearerTokenFetchTask.class.getName());

    final static String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH2_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
    final static String USER_AGENT = "TwitterMotion User Agent";

    protected String mApplicationOnlyBearerToken;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... tokens) {
        String consumerKey = tokens[0];
        String consumerSecret = tokens[0];
        String encodedCredentials = encodeKeysFrom(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH2_TOKEN);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "29");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

            writeRequest(urlConnection, "grant_type=client_credentials");
            String jsonResponse = readResponse(urlConnection);
            logger.log(INFO, "jsonResponse of the bearer oauth request: ", jsonResponse);

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "HTTP 403 (Forbidden) returned from Twitter API call for bearer token. " +
                        "Check values of Consumer Key and Consumer Secret in tokens.properties");
                throw new RejectedAuthorizationException(urlConnection.getResponseCode(), "HTTP 403 (Forbidden) returned attempting to get Twitter API bearer token");
            }

            JSONObject jsonResponseObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

            if (jsonResponseObject != null) {
                mApplicationOnlyBearerToken = (String) jsonResponseObject.get("access_token");
            } else {
                // TODO
            }
            return mApplicationOnlyBearerToken;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String applicationOnlyBearerToken) {
        this.mApplicationOnlyBearerToken = applicationOnlyBearerToken;
    }

    public String getApplicationOnlyBearerToken() {
        return mApplicationOnlyBearerToken;
    }

    private String encodeKeysFrom(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret) {
        try {
            String encodedConsumerKey = URLEncoder.encode(consumerKey, "UTF-8");
            String encodedConsumerSecret = URLEncoder.encode(consumerSecret, "UTF-8");

            String combinedEncodedKey = encodedConsumerKey + ":" + encodedConsumerSecret;
            byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(combinedEncodedKey.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            return new String(encodedBytes);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean writeRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, String requestBody)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        try {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
            bufferedWriter.write(requestBody);
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }


    private String readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But I am getting `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

I also added permission on manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I can not understand what is the issue actually. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the bug.

```
String consumerKey = tokens[0];
String consumerSecret = tokens[0];
```

It should be

```
String consumerSecret = tokens[1];
```